# pandas merging/joining data to a dataframe while looping

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

I am trying to merge or join data to a df while looping through my accounts.

First I set up an empty data frame indexed by all the months:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [2014-09-30, 2014-09-30, 2014-10-31, 2014-10-31, 2014-11-30, 2014-11-30, 2014-12-31, 2015-01-31, 2015-02-28, 2015-03-31]
```

Next I loop trough all the accounts to add the values to the data frame.

```
for a in accts:

        cf = Cashflow.objects.all ().filter ( id = a.id ).order_by ( 'month' ).values ( 'month', 'value' )

        df2 = read_frame ( cf )
        df2 = df2.set_index ( 'month' )

        df = pd.merge ( df2, how = 'left', left_index = True, right_index = True )
```

But I am getting duplicate data in my output:

```
month                        
2014-09-30   535400  122928.0
2014-09-30   535400  122928.0
2014-10-31   530719  107389.0
2014-10-31   530719  107389.0
2014-11-30   512009   97654.0
2014-11-30   512009   97654.0
2014-12-31   482277       0.0
2015-01-31   474815       0.0
```

I have tried different solutions.

I can delete duplicate rows but that is just a patch on bad code.

Is this the best method? Should it be a join and not a merge?

Answer (score 1):

You have duplicate dates in the index you have created for the empty database that you started with. Why?

Answer (score 1):

You have duplicates in your indices.

You can drop them by `df.drop_duplicates()`